# How do i deserialize a Jsonp response into splited string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseData);
string[] result = msg.Split(',');
string statuscode = result[0];
string RRR = result[1];
string status = result[2];
```

The code above shows my response after sending a request to an API with a `responseData` as `jsonp ({"statuscode":"025","RRR":"260007663696","status":"Payment Reference generated"})`
When i ran the code, i got an error message complaining about `var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseData);`

How do i go about converting my jsonp response into splitted string values?

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of JSON.  Your JSON string represents an object with 3 properties (`statuscode`, `RRR` and `status`).  You are trying to deserialize into a `string` which is incorrect.  You need to define a class that has those 3 properties in it and deserialize into _that_

Comment: Can you post the definition of `RemitaResponse` in your answer?  If you attempted to deserailize into an object and it did not work we need to see that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Regex` to convert your JSONP to JSON, by stripping the outer function away and extracting only the JSON inside the brackets:

```
var jsonp = "jsonp({ \"statuscode\":\"025\",\"RRR\":\"260007663696\",\"status\":\"Payment Reference generated\"})";
var jsonMatch = Regex.Match(jsonp, @"\((?<json>.*)\)");
var json = jsonMatch.Groups["json"].Value;
```

After that, you can deserialize using your preferred method with the JSON.Net library. Here's one way using the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(json);
var status = token["status"].Value<string>();
var statusCode = token["statuscode"].Value<string>();
var rr = token["RRR"].Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON payload represents an *object* with 3 properties.  I recommend making a class that represents this object so you can serialize/deserialize:

```
public class SomeObject  //Rename to something more fitting
{
    public string StatusCode {get;set;}
    public string RRR {get;set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
}
```

Then when you deseralize, use this new class as the generic parameter (not `string` like you are currently doing):

```
var someObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(json);
```

Now you can access the properties like you would any other instance:

```
Console.WriteLine(someObj.Status);
// etc, etc
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dIRA3O)

Comment: Threw exception `JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: j. Path '', line 0, position 0. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't creating a class to deserialize your JSON, you can convert your JSON to a dynamic object and access the properties freely:

```
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(responseData);
string statuscode = result.statuscode;
string RRR = result.RRR;
string status = result.status;
```